# Given a polynomial with integer coefficients and prime independent term, show that any root has absolute value greater than 1.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I was looking at exercises about algebraic structures, and in ring theory I stumbled upon this problem.

> Given $p$ a prime number and $f(x)=\pm p + a_{1}x+\cdots+x^{n} \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ so that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} |a_{i}| < p$. (Note that $a_{n}=1$.) Show that if $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of $f(x)$, then $|\alpha| >1$. Is $f(x)$ irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x]$ and $\mathbb Q[x]$?

The thing is I need this criteria to verify some polynomials are irreducible and I don't know how to show this.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Are you also interested to see about whether or not $f(x)$ is irreducible?

Comment: I think I can work my way with that, if I can't get there maybe I will ask! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hi, funny thing, I've been given this as an excercise and immediately recalled this question (guess my memory is still fine...). My answer is of course not complete, and I'd be glad to see how the first part implies that the polynomial is irreducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $t$ is a root, then we have  $p=|p|=|a_1t+a_2t^2+...+t^n|\leq|a_1t|+|a_2t^2|+...+|t^n|$.

If $|t|\leq 1$, then $|t^n|\leq 1$ for every $n$, and we have $|a_1t|+|a_2t^2|+...+|t^n|\leq|a_1|+...+|a_n|<p$
and that's a contradiction.